# Where should I put view specific properties for a model in a collection in MVVM (Knockout.js specifically)?

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

Say I have an ko.observableArray of Person models (below):

```
// Model
var Person = function () {
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.age = ko.observable();
};

// View Model
var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray([
        new Person("Bob", 21),
        new Person("Bill", 25)
    ])
};
```

With the following HTML:

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="visible: isVisible">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where should I put `isVisible`?

**Model** - It seems wrong to put it on the Model since it has nothing to do with the person.

**View Model** - I need to have it be per Person, so putting it on the View Model wouldn't work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdavis/LkqTU/6873/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have a model in JavaScript. Just have a view model. Your models should exist only on the server, where you're actually storing the objects.

In this case, Person is really a view model. You can then put lots of Person objects in your main view model, but each person is still a view model.

Thus, put your isVisible property on your Person view model.

Comment: Also try to use a name thats more connected to the business rule than isVisible. isVible is a view specific information, for example in the ViewModel the bool member might be called valid, active or similar. And then bound to the visible binding

Comment: @Anders I probably should have specified this in the question. I was thinking of using isVisible for a collapse/expand action in which case it is entirely view specific (which was why I was hesitant to put it on Person).

Comment: I'd still put it on Person, since it is your view model. If you'd like to keep Person a model, then you'll need a separate PersonViewModel. But like I said, typically, your JS contains just your ViewModels. Your Model exists only on the server.

Comment: Judah's answer is correct, I was just pointing out that its better to give it a name thats connected to the logic/domain why its visible or not. Hope I'm making myself clear :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between Model and ViewModel. In your case, Model is the ViewModel and what you've called the viewModel is an instance of the ViewModel, i.e., once you define objects with ko.observables, it is a ViewModel only used on the client side. Any data-binding attribute that you need should be defined on the ViewModel. So, in summary, you should define the isVisible in the Person object definition, as an observable or a computed value, based on your requirements.